yarn suddenly started to throw Request failed "401 Unauthorized" when installing private module
Using yarn and a private node module dependency, suddenly it started to fail locally and in App Center.
Error: https://npm.pkg.github.com/download/<MODULE>/0.2.22/69c91a691598d54818a22a72c971fdbd756ae62d: Request failed "401 Unauthorized"
    at ResponseError.ExtendableBuiltin (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.22/libexec/lib/cli.js:696:66)
    at new ResponseError (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.22/libexec/lib/cli.js:802:124)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.22/libexec/lib/cli.js:66750:16)
    at Request.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at module.exports.Request.onRequestResponse (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.22/libexec/lib/cli.js:142287:10)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (node:_http_client:698:27)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:119:17)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:540:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:519:28)

Tried recreating ~/.npmrc, tried yarn cache clean, tried removing yarn.lock, tried many possible workarounds from similar questions but same issue persists.
After removing yarn.lock the error changes a bit:
Error: https://npm.pkg.github.com/<MODULE>: unauthenticated: User cannot be authenticated with the token provided.
    at params.callback [as _callback] (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.22/libexec/lib/cli.js:66680:18)
    at self.callback (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.22/libexec/lib/cli.js:141410:22)
    at Request.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.22/libexec/lib/cli.js:142382:10)
    at Request.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.22/libexec/lib/cli.js:142304:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:633:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:531:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)

What is strange is that in github it works (with a yarn cache clean added in pre-build scripts).
Also re-creation of token for that repository doesn't seem to work.
Local deps:
yarn version 1.22.22
npm version 10.7.0
node version v20.15.1


Generate a new token for that repository
by someone with access to the repo (not necessarily the repo owner).
Details:
To generate a new authentication token for accessing a private node module in a GitHub repository, you need to create a personal access token (PAT) through GitHub.
This token will act as your credentials for downloading and installing private node modules via npm (Node Package Manager) or yarn.
Below are the steps to create and use a new auth token for a private node module:
Step 1: Generate Personal Access Token (PAT) on GitHub
Log in to GitHub: Open your browser and log into your GitHub account.
Click on your profile picture in the top right corner, then select "Settings" from the dropdown menu.
Developer Settings: On the left sidebar of the settings page, scroll down and click on "Developer settings."
Personal Access Tokens: In the left sidebar under "Developer settings," click on "Personal access tokens." Then click on the "Generate new token" button.
Token Description: Give your token a descriptive name so you can remember its purpose.
Select Scopes:
-For accessing private repositories through npm, you should select at least the repo scope, which grants full control over private repositories.

Optionally, you might consider selecting other scopes depending on your specific needs, but for most uses involving npm, repo is sufficient. In my case a web type token was selected.

Generate Token: Click the "Generate token" button at the bottom of the page. Make sure to copy your new personal access token. You won't be able to see it again once you leave this page.
Step 2: Configure npm by editing .npmrc to use the new token.
After you have your token, you need to configure npm or yarn to use this token when accessing private repositories.
Create or Edit .npmrc: You need to create or edit .npmrc file in your project directory or your home directory (~/.npmrc).
Add Token to .npmrc:
    @your-username:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/  
   //npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=YOUR_GITHUB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN
   

Note: I started to think the token could be expired and that is not a yarn issue when I noticed both yarn and npm install commands failed with the same error.
